# REGEX Как указать не чувствительнсть к регистру для русского алфавита?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В регулярных выражениях, (?i) - обеспечивает нечувствительность к регистру, но только для латиницы, для русского (и я подозреваю любого другого алфавита), это не работает.
Как можно указать нечувствительность к регистру для русского алфавита?

Comment: флаг `u` добавьте для других алфавитов. Должно `i` везде работать. Либо пример в студию

Comment: `[А-Яа-яёЁ]` - можно попробовать, но `ui` как написали выше должно решать проблему для unicode

Comment: Уважаемый teran - Вы совершенно правы, флаг u решает проблему.